# How can i inner join a subquery in JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I need  a JPQL for the MySQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
  ON t1.id = t2.table1.id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table1 t3 
            INNER JOIN table2 t4 ON t3.id = t4.table1.id 
            WHERE t3.name = 'xxx') subTable 
  ON t1.number = subTable.number 
WHERE t1.number = '5' 
  AND id = '3'
```

Comment: Without any information about the structure of your entities its quite hard to tell something about the necessary JPQL query.

Comment: Relationship between table1 and table2 is table2 have a field of table1's id. Then few columns are common for table1, table2 which belongs to other table (for ex: table3) Here we no need to consider table3 since we inner join table1 and table2 by the columns in these two tables itself

Comment: I'm not talking about the structure of your database. To tell about the JPQL query I need to know about how your entity objects are designed, how the mappings between the entities are implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query seems quite pathological, perhaps say what result you are trying to query, and include your object model.

In general, JPQL does not support sub-selects in the from clause, so your query is not directly convertable to JPQL.

You can always just execute it as a JPA native SQL query, since you seem to be comfortable with SQL than JPQL.